# JDeveloper error while creating a stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

When trying to create a stored procedure in JDeveloper 11g r1 (1.1.1.7) I get the message :" a severe error..." and the option to save my current work and exit JDev.
The log:

```
 Invoking command: Delete Previous[ from oracle.ide.ceditor.CodeEditor ]
Invoking command: Insert[ from oracle.ide.ceditor.CodeEditor ]
Uncaught exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
  j.lang.String.substring(String.java:1934)
  o.dbtools.parser.plsql.SuggestedItem.getDisplayText(SuggestedItem.java:181)
  o.javatools.editor.insight.ListDataItemCellRenderer.getPrototypeCell(ListDataItemCellRenderer.java:150)
  o.javatools.editor.insight.ListInsightView.setData(ListInsightView.java:209)
  o.dbtools.raptor.insight.CompletionInsight.refreshSuggestedItemsList(CompletionInsight.java:1031)
  o.dbtools.raptor.insight.CompletionInsight.complete(CompletionInsight.java:898)
  o.dbtools.raptor.insight.CompletionInsight$InsightThread.run(CompletionInsight.java:510)
```

This error shows up when editing the procedure. I use Database Navigator for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a real IDE: IntelliJ.  Who uses JDeveloper anymore?  No one.

Comment: Two reasons: i use it at work, secondly: I use some Oracle specific API's, weblogic server. Could IntelliJ be used with some existing sources created with JDveloper?

Comment: Of course.  I'm sorry that you have to use such an out of date, small market share tool.